# AWS Cloudshell unable to start docker service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I have been created `EKS` cluster.

Now, I'm trying to create `docker image` to push it into my private `ECR` so I just installed `docker` using the following command:

```
amazon-linux-extras install docker
```

The installation succeed but when I'm tried to use `docker` I got the following:

```
[cloudshell-user@ip-10-0-73-203 ~]$ docker images
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

When I'm trying to start `docker` service I got:

```
[cloudshell-user@ip-10-0-73-203 ~]$ sudo systemctl start docker
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
```

How can I solve it? Should I need to use another user?

Answer (score 9):

After installing Docker on AWS CloudShell, I encountered an issue starting Docker. To resolve this, I ran the following commands in the terminal:

Update and install docker on cloudshell:

```
sudo yum update -y
sudo amazon-linux-extras install docker
```

Then, I started Docker by running the command:

```
sudo dockerd
```

After that, I opened a new terminal and ran the command:

```
sudo docker ps
```

to confirm that Docker was running properly. This command allowed me to view a list of active Docker containers.

Comment: This works on June 2023.

Comment: Not working in December 23. Cloudshell migrated from Amazon Linux 2 to Amazon Linux 2023 (AL2023) and doesn't support Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL) right now, so amazon-linux-extras does not exist.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately this cannot be done (today).

> Currently, the AWS CloudShell compute environment doesn't support Docker containers.

From the [doc page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudshell/latest/userguide/vm-specs.html).

An alternative would be to run a full fledge instance using [Cloud9](https://aws.amazon.com/cloud9/). Note Cloud9 has a cost as it is backed by an EC2 instance.

Comment: so if there is no possible to use ```docker``` on cloud shell, how does people able to use ```EKS``` or how can I simply create docker image and push it into ```ECR``` ?

Comment: You can use both the `AWS CLI` as well as `kubectl` to "use" `EKS`. You can't build a container with a local Docker and push it to ECR with CloudShell. For the latter you can either use CodeBuild (but this assumes that you are already automatic stuff) or you could use a Cloud9 environment (which allows for the docker build / docker push).